# Add Literal Percent Sign (%) to my calculation

Tags: mysql, sql, percentage

I want to add a `%` sign to the derived values from the example below, is it possible? Do I have to somehow use `CAST(n)`?

```
ROUND(qy.TotalUnits/qy.TotalCalls *100) AS "Total Conv" +'%'
```

Comment: String concatenation in MySQL [is done with `CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `CONCAT` in MySQL to concatenate `%` with the values received from `ROUND(<...>)`:

```
CONCAT(ROUND(qy.TotalUnits/qy.TotalCalls *100),'%')
```

At first, in MySQL `+` is used for arithmetic operations, secondly, you are trying to concatenate  `%` with the alias, not values.

Answer (score 1):

CONCAT(ROUND(qy.TotalUnits/qy.TotalCalls*100),'%')

Using CONCAT convert it to string type.

So please be alert